# Python virtual environments and space management (Pipenv in particular)

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I have recently grown interest in learning how to use virtual environments with Python.
As you probably already know, they are useful when in need of multiple versions of the same package. As far as I understood, using pip you can't differentiate between versions since it just uses the package's name.

I will take as an example Pipenv, which seems to be a new powerful tool also announced as the new standard by the PyPA. I fairly understand what, how, and why Pipenv does the (basic) things. What I don't understand (or better, what puzzles me) is how Pipenv (or any virtual environment tool in Python for what I know) manages space on the disk.

With Pip you usually install packages in one place, then you simple import them in you code, that's it.
With Pipenv (or similar) you create a virtual environment in which you have everything installed and it cannot communicate with the external world (which is kind of the point, I know).

Now let's suppose I am working on ProjectA, then on ProjectB. Both will have their environment (somewhere within ~.virtualenvs, for Pipenv).
Let's also suppose that even if the two projects have different high-level dependencies, they have one sub-dependence in common. I mean, same name same version.
When I do "pipenv install *thatpackage*" in each of the cases, it will be downloaded and stored separately in each case. Am I correct?

If I'm right, isn't this a waste of space? I would have 2 copies of the same package on my disk. If this is reiterated for many packages you can guess how much space is wasted when working on many different projects.

Comment: Well, yes it uses more space than if you had it in a single location. However this is not the purpose of virtualenv. Virtualenv is made for managing your packages in development environment (in particular when you work on several projects that have different versions of the same dependencies). If you think the dependencies of a specific project are too heavy, delete them, you'll be able to rebuild everything in seconds.

Comment: it's a bad practice to create a common package repository(but its possible). Main purpose of _virtualenv_ (read pipenv) is to create an _isolated_ environment.

Comment: This is why I don't use virtualenv in my local machine (or laptop), I try to keep only one version (the most recent-compatible with other packages) of each package, I also consider a code with a high dependency to a specific old version of any package is a possible code smell (or tightly coupled design...), I say the same for other build tool (e.g. gradlew, npm...)

Comment: What I plan to do (and haven't yet) is to create my own local PyPI repository mirror on my laptop.  the idea is to have all the packages I normally used cached locally, then as I create and delete virtual environments, they can draw from my local repository rather than requiring internet connectivity.